# How to load property/config files from external directory in springboot

Tags: spring-boot

I have some config files ,sharing with other system. So, I want to synchronize these files by Git before the application startup each time. The application is been archived to Spring-boot JAR file.

First of all ,I made an experiment . I tried to load the logback config file:logback.xml from the external directory. According to the springboot doc http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher.html . I add the load.path param to the startup command.

```
java -Dloader.home="./" -Dloader.path="sds_ser/" -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.profiles.active=test
```

The sds_ser is the directory of the logback.xml. Which along with the service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.But startup failure,the logback.xml could not be found!

Any one can help ? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `/sds_ser/logback.xml` ?

Comment: Yes ,I tried,but failure again!

Comment: Check here for the externalized configuration https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-logback-for-logging. It should work for you. Looks like it needs `logging.file`

Comment: Thanks! The "logging.file" flag seems to be used to  config the log file location. It is not related my problem.My final goal is to load config files from sds_ser folder,such as logback.xml. There are so many config files, so the file name could not be specified in command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a custom file to be loaded onto the classpath of your spring boot jar (uber jar) you can do that by setting the classpath during run.

java -cp "/sds_ser/:/pathtoyourjar/service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dspring.profiles.active=test org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher

This is assuming your file is in the path /sds_ser on the server.
The -Dloader.path does only the following as per documentation

> loader.path can contain directories (which are scanned recursively for
>   jar and zip files), archive paths, a directory within an archive that
>   is scanned for jar files (for example, dependencies.jar!/lib), or
>   wildcard patterns (for the default JVM behavior). Archive paths can be
>   relative to loader.home or anywhere in the file system with a
>   jar:file: prefix.

Also as per the below site

http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/01/how-classpath-work-in-java.html

> It's also worth noting that when you use the  java -jar command line
>   option to run your Java program as an executable JAR, then the
>   CLASSPATH environment variable will be ignored, and also the -cp and
>   -classpath switches will be ignored.

So you have to give the main class for this to run, which is org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher

Answer (score 0):

I use the following for overriding properties from external location.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "file:/var/tmp/${spring.application.name}/${MY_APP_PROFILE:h2}/conf/override.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer() {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        configurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return configurer;
    }
}
```